# Master Slave Approach in RDS Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds, master-slave

How can I implement Master Slave approach in RDS database? Actually what i want is, for improving the performance I want to implement Master Slave approach in my RDS Database. I think if i can separate the read and create/update operations into different databases I can improve the perfomace. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually very easy with RDS - you just need to create an RDS Read Replica. This will do the replication asynchronously, which will improve your RDS write replica performance by not overloading it.

Note, different types of read replicas are available depending on the SQL flavour you use. Generally there are up to 5 direct read replicas of an instance, but Aurora for example offers 15.

Please see:
https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/read-replicas/

Comment: Ok if I create read replica then whether i have to make change in my connection code? Or the AWS automatically handle the read queries

Comment: If you have a read replica, you will need to modify your code to run read queries against the read replica.